# How can i give Administrator SE_TCB_NAME privilege

Tags: python-3.x, window, windows-services

I am working on a python service where i can create process for loged in user (via token) the problem is it works fin when i run cmd as a LocalSystem(using psexec) but anytime i run it as Admin i get client does not have privilege error and am using python3.11

`

```
def AdjustPriv(priv, enable=1):
    # Adjust privileges for the current process
    flags = win32security.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | win32security.TOKEN_QUERY
    htoken = win32security.OpenProcessToken(win32api.GetCurrentProcess(), flags)
    id = win32security.LookupPrivilegeValue(None, priv)
    if enable:
        newPriv = [(id, win32security.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED)]
    else:
        newPriv = [(id, 0)]
    win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges(htoken, 0, newPriv)

AdjustPriv(win32security.SE_TCB_NAME)

console_session_id = win32ts.WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()


#having issue with this line
console_user_token = win32ts.WTSQueryUserToken(console_session_id)`
```

how can i give Administrator SE_TCB_NAME privilege